# Postman: Read a csv file placed in aws using Postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

How can I read a csv file placed in aws using Postman ?

I am able to get list of files and folders places in aws using
aws url:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/partnertrackingconfigurationdev/?list-type=2
access key, secret key and session token.

But, I would like to read the csv file placed at below url using Postman.

aws url:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/partnertrackingconfigurationdev/?list-type=2&Key=QAInputData/CarrierTrackingNumbers.csv

Please help

Answer (score 0):

On s3 in AWS you can explicite configure folder/file permissions. Is this here what you are looking for?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/userguide/web_share_link.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workdocs/latest/userguide/permissions.html#doc_perms

**EDIT**

I am also a little bit confused, that in your URL that after the 'RequestParams' (?list-type=2&....) you use again a 'Path' (/CarrierTrackingNumbers.csv).

Should it not be:
`https://s3.amazonaws.com/partnertrackingconfigurationdev/CarrierTrackingNumbers.csv?list-type=2&Key=QAInputData`